# Grails unit test verify mock method called

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mockito, grails-2.0

In my unit test, I mock a service (which is a ref of the class under test).

Like:

```
given:
def mockXxService = mockFor(XxService)
mockXxService.demand.xxx(1) {->}
service.xxService = mockXxService
when:
service.yyy()
then:
// verify mockXxService's xxx method is invoked.
```

For my unit test, I want to verify that `mockXxService.xxx()` is called. But grails document's `mockControl.verify()` doesn't work for me. Not sure how to use it correctly.

It is very similar to mockito's verify method.

Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `spock` for your unit test, you should be easily able to use spock's `MockingApi` check invocations:

```
given:
    def mockXxService = Mock(XxService)
    service.xxService = mockXxService
when:
    service.yyy()
then:
    1 * mockXxService.xxx(_) //assert xxx() is called once
```

You could get more insight about mocking from [spockframework docs](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking).

You can even stub and mock that while mocking the concerned service as:

```
def mockXxService = Mock(XxService) {
    1 * xxx(_)
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. It said: Too few invocations for:

1 * xxx.yyy()   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

Comment: That is a good sign. You are on right track then. Refer docs again. If possible provide the exact implementation of the service class and the usage of `XxSevice` inside it. That might help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Mockito-like behavior in Grails unit tests - just use Mockito. It is far more convenient than Grails' mocking methods.