# How can I test a service injected to other service in Grails?

Tags: grails, spock

I got an error at calling a service from other service.

```
| Running 13 unit tests... 1 of 13
| Failure:  test myAction(MyServiceSpec)
2015.05.27/02:17:09  ERROR StackTrace -- Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method saveUserRole() on null object
```

I made two service as below.

```
class MyService {
    def userRoleService
    def myAction(){
        def userQuery = User.where{username == "test1"}.get()
        def roleQuery = Role.where{authority == "ROLE_ADMIN"}.get()
        if (userQuery && roleQuery){
            userRoleService.saveUserRole(userQuery, roleQuery)
        }
    }
}

class UserRoleService{
    def saveUserRole(user, role){
        new UserRole(role: role, user:user).save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

I want to test `myAction()` of `MyService`, so I made `MyServiceSpec` as below.

```
@TestFor(DatabaseService)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def userRoleService 
    def setup() { }
    def cleanup() { }
    void "test myAction"(){
        setup:
        mockDomain( Role,[ [authority:"ROLE_ADMIN"], [authority:"ROLE_USER"] ] )
        mockDomain( User,[ [username:"test1",password:"1234"] ] )
        mockDomain( UserRole )

        when: "call the action"
        service.myAction()

        then:
        UserRole.count() == 1
    }   
}
```

This error is caused when `userRoleService.saveUserRole(userQuery, roleQuery)` is called.

How can I test of `myAction()` of `MyService` without error?

### ----

***UPDATE***

I changed the Spec Class as below.

```
@TestFor(DatabaseService)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() { }
    def cleanup() { }
    void "test myAction"(){
        setup:
        mockDomain( Role,[ [authority:"ROLE_ADMIN"], [authority:"ROLE_USER"] ] )
        mockDomain( User,[ [username:"test1",password:"1234"] ] )
        mockDomain( UserRole )
        def userQuery = User.where{username == "test1"}.get()
        def roleQuery = Role.where{authority == "ROLE_ADMIN"}.get()
        def mockUserRoleService = Mock(UserRoleService){
            1 * saveUserRole(userQuery, roleQuery) >> new UserRole(role: roleQuery, user:userQuery).save(flush: true)
        }
        service.userRoleService = mockUserRoleService

        when: "call the action"
        service.myAction()

        then:
        UserRole.count() == 1
    }   
}
```

The test recognizes the service class, thanks.

But it seems this test case is not good or this program design is not good.

Do you have any suggestion of referctoring this code?

Comment: Usage of `userRoleService` in `MyService` has to be mocked as well. DI is not possible in Unit Specs, i.e just using `def userRoleService` will not make the dependent service available in unit spec.

Comment: How can I make the mock of userRoleService in myAction()?

Comment: on a sidenote: it's uncommon to name your classes starting with a lower case letter.

Comment: [A detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829220/grails-testing-with-spock-which-mocking-framework-select/17871827#17871827) and a [brief one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520212/grails-unit-test-verify-mock-method-called/21520409#21520409).

Comment: I changed SpecClass as the UPDATE section of my question, imitating [the detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829220/grails-testing-with-spock-which-mocking-framework-select/17871827#17871827) but it seems not working.

Comment: Thanks, I could passed the test finally. But it seems this test case is not good as a test or this program design is not good. By the way, thank you for you guys supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments, I changed the Spec Class as below.

```
@TestFor(DatabaseService)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() { }
    def cleanup() { }
    void "test myAction"(){
        setup:
        mockDomain( Role,[ [authority:"ROLE_ADMIN"], [authority:"ROLE_USER"] ] )
        mockDomain( User,[ [username:"test1",password:"1234"] ] )
        mockDomain( UserRole )
        def userQuery = User.where{username == "test1"}.get()
        def roleQuery = Role.where{authority == "ROLE_ADMIN"}.get()
        def mockUserRoleService = Mock(UserRoleService){
            1 * saveUserRole(userQuery, roleQuery) >> new UserRole(role: roleQuery, user:userQuery).save(flush: true)
        }
        service.userRoleService = mockUserRoleService

        when: "call the action"
        service.myAction()

        then:
        UserRole.count() == 1
    }   
}
```

The test recognizes the service class, thanks.

But it seems this test case is not good or this program design is not good.

Do you have any suggestion of referctoring this code?